# NHibernate and a REST Service Layer

Tags: .net, web-services, nhibernate, rest

If ADO.NET Data Services (Astoria) adds a REST layer on top of Microsoft's ADO.NET Entity Framework, is there an equivalent project that adds a REST layer on top of NHibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit (2012-02-08) Updated link: [MeanFiddler](http://meanfiddler.sourceforge.net/index.html)

Comment: +1 Looks good. I'll check this out. I wonder which of the many REST frameworks is going to help standardize the way clients interact with pagination, filtering, joining, nesting, etc...

Comment: He's upgraded his blog but not archived posts from 2007 so you'll have to contact him to get the details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for something similar.  I see the project mentioned by Jonathan Parker can be found on sourceforge here:

http://meanfiddler.sourceforge.net

But it looks like it hasn't been touched since 2007, so it probably won't be that useful.