# Exposing entities via a nHibernate implementation RIA Services with querystring queries

Tags: linq, wcf, nhibernate, ria

I once read a blog post and cannot find it anymore. drat!

It was about a guy who setup a wcf service (I guess RIA, but could have been something else) exposing the model via IQueryable to the querystring.

Sou you could say

http://host/articles/123/ratings

and you'd get a list (soap or json) of serialized Rating entities (the properties which had some attribute attached) which pertained to an article with id 123.
All this with nHibernate / nh linq in the back and in surprisingly few lines of code.

Anyone knows what I am talking about? Experiences, suggestions?

Comment: guess it was here
http://wildermuth.com/2008/07/21/NHibernate_LINQ_with_ADO_NET_Data_Services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See:
[NHibernate and a REST Service Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471753/nhibernate-and-a-rest-service-layer)

Might be worth emailing him?